# Trouble using eventsource with Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, frontend, server-sent-events

I am having trouble connecting my backend nodeJs Server-Sent Event to my Next.JS app.

Here is part of my Server-Side Code that essentially just sends a stringed version of a object JSON

> Server Side

```
    app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
      // Set the response headers for SSE
        res.set({
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
        });

        setInterval(() => {
            if (clients[0]!= null || clients[0] != undefined){
            
                res.write(JSON.stringify(clients[0]));
            }
            }, 1000);

   })
```

> Front End side in NextJS

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import EventSource from 'eventsource';
const eventSource = new EventSource('http://192.168.1.2:3001/data');


// Define a custom component that listens to SSE events
const SSEComponent = () => {
const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
 // Define a handler for the message event
 eventSource.onmessage = (e) => {
   console.log(e)
   setData(JSON.parse(e.data));
 };

 // Define a handler for the error event
 eventSource.onerror = (e) => {
   console.log("error")
   console.error(e);
 };

 return () => {
   console.log("closing")
   eventSource.close();
 };
}, []); 


return (
 <div>
   {data ? (
     <p>Data from the server: {data.hello}</p>
   ) : (
     <p>Loading...</p>
   )}
 </div>
);
};

export default SSEComponent;
```

I know that my server is operating. Because when I go to the url of the app.get() function . I can see the data on the webpage.

However, on my front end, I am not grabbing the data. I know that EventSource is the culprit because I am getting a warning that says

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'eventsource'.

Why cant my app find eventsource is it not built into JS?